# FFmpeg HLS single file extension and format by byte ranges

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm attempting to take a 5-minute video file and produce a ***single-file*** HLS playlist with this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -hls_time 4 -hls_flags single_file -hls_list_size 0 video.m3u8
```

Produces a playlist like so:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:535424@0
video.ts
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:316592@535424
video.ts
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:285384@852016
video.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

What I wanted to:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:535424@0
video-0-535424.txt
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:316592@535424
video-535424-316592.txt
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:285384@852016
video-852016-285384.txt
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Or:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:535424@0
video.txt#0-535424
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:316592@535424
video.txt#535424-316592
#EXTINF:5.338667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:285384@852016
video.txt#852016-285384
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I still want to convert to one single **.ts/or anything else**, just want to edit how it write in **video.m3u8**. Is it possible with ffmpeg only? If so, how can it be done? Or are there any js/nodejs module that can rewrite **video.m3u8** to something like `video.txt#range-here`

Comment: What do the txt files do in your example?

Comment: I want to use cloudflare cache for fast loading but it only cache some type of file like `js/css etc` that txt can be html or anything else

Comment: You are asking if you can change the file extension? As in still write a TS formated file, but using a .txt name?

Comment: So you simply wish to have a TS file with `txt` extension?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I'm asking if I can change the *video.ts* in *video.m3u8* to *video.txt*. No need to change the file extension of the ffmpeg output file

Comment: be wary of trying to do this with cloudflare, if the ratio ends up being too much they'll deactivate your account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is, you can parse the .m3u8 file using [m3u8-parser](https://github.com/videojs/m3u8-parser)

You need to parse the .m3u8 file, extract each line  and check if that line contains .ts. If it contains, replace it with .txt. That's the hack i did in my project.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

To change the segment file name you can use this parameter when using `single_file` flag

```
-hls_segment_filename video.txt
```

or for normal hls

```
-hls_segment_filename video_%d.txt
```

You can use any filename or extension and FFmpeg will still output the segment in the format you choose